# How can I dump all guzzle responses into txt files?

Tags: php, mocking, phpunit, stub, guzzle

I've been reading the documentation:

http://guzzle3.readthedocs.org/testing/unit-testing.html

and I know how to use .txt files as response mocks for testing; but what I want to achieve is to grab the actual responses of my application. My webapp relies on hundreds of different API calls and when one fails it is hard to know where is the failure, so I want to use the .txt response files to 'inject' a working response for debugging purposes.

Hope that's clear enough,

thanks in advance.